# Is it possible to do multiple certificates verification?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

In my current project, the server has two certificates signed by different CAs; both has to be verified for one session (like below). Is it doable? Thanks a lot.

```
server ==(cert1, cert2)==> client
```

Comment: Please mention the scenario where you received two certificates. Means, how will server send the two certificates.

Comment: @dbasic that depends on server configuration, but is easily doable.

Comment: Originally, I thought modifying the SSL certificate verification callback would be enough. But I was wrong. The challenge, as I see, is how to deal with two private keys. It seems only possible if getting more deep into the protocol, which is not easily doable.

Answer (score 0):

Once, you received two or more certificates, it is doable.

Verifying the two certificates is like a two step process:

1. Verify certificate 1
2. Verify certificate 2

Provide that you have CAs certificates and CAs must be trusted by you.

If CA's are intermediate CA then you must have chain of the certificate towards root certificate.

For verification, you can use OpenSSL function such as `X509_verify` where you will need CA public key and the certificate.

Comment: I think of something like that too: pack two certificates in a bundle and the server can load that file. But I am not sure how to do deal with two private keys. The standard TLS/SSL protocol only uses one private key to encrypt messages in handshake. If the other private key is not used, then the verification process is incomplete.